# Finding Total Pay by Certain Conditions

Tags: ms-access

Generate a query to count and display the number of full time and number of part time employees, the total pay of all fulltime employees and the total pay of all the part time employees.

Workings:

So I have the fields Status and Total Pay. I added the field Status and the field Status again which is a Count but it is hidden. I then added a new field called "Number of Each Status Type". I then referenced it to Status and gruped it by count.

This gave the desired first two rows of the image.

I am not sure on how to get the third though. How would I get the Total Pay by Status. Any help will be appreicated.

[It has look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ejig.png)

[What I have for Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBXC0.png)

Comment: Please post your query so we can see ...

Comment: Ok. I just did.

Comment: Put the Total Pay in your query, and Total by Sum.

Comment: Does 'Status' indicate 'Full Time' and 'Part Time'? If so, change your 'Count' for the 'Status' field to 'GroupBy', then add the 'Total Pay' column and make that a 'Sum'.. or include 'Base Pay' and 'Overtime' and Sum if needed.

Comment: Thank you :) how would I make it so that it would have the correct Field name? It is called SumOfTotalPay right now.

Comment: If you mean you want the output field name to be 'Total Pay', then the field name would be "Total Pay: [Total Pay]", or change the SQL to Sum(Bonus.[Total Pay]) AS [Total Pay]